# How to make a square sized HTML table fill screen in Android webview

Tags: android, html, css, android-layout

Hope someone can help me with this.

In my Android app I have a fragment with a webview (and some other views). The webview displays a page with a HTML table. This table is a game board, with 8 x 8 cells (like a Chess board).

The problem is that I want the table to fill the screen as much as possible. But at the same time it also needs to be perfectly squared (width and height must stay the same).

How can I do that? Setting width and height to 100% in the HTML wont't make it square. And if I set them to fixed numbers they don't resize on different screen sizes. I also tried to use WebView.getWidth() to get the size of the webview, and then scale the table to fill it. But I can't know the size of the webview until the page is loaded, and I can't load the page until I know the size of the webview...

---

A few other details (I don't know if they are relevant):

The layout in the fragment is inflated from a layout file in Fragment.onCreateView. Then, in Fragment.onActivityCreated I add the webview to the fragment by Java code. The HTML is also created dynamically by Java code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a soloution to this:

1. Instead of trying to get the size of the webview, I take the size of the fragment and subtract the size of the other views. This gives me the remaining space available for the webview.
2. Even in onResume all the dimensions are zero, though. So in onResume I create a Handler which runs after half a second. Here I create the HTML document to be displayed.
3. I set the size of the HTML document to be half the size of the space available in the fragment. (I have no idea why I need to half it.)

This is an ugly soloution, but it works both in landscape and portrait mode on both my phone and tablet.